# Automatic marking or tracking of edited features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, editing, fields-attributes

I'm working with ArcMap 10.2.

What is a good way to mark or find edited features in order to keep track of them without manual field updating?

Is there a way to have ArcMap automatically update a value in a certain field when I edit a features, for example when I move a point?

Comment: Have you looked into Editor Tracking?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy when you use the File-Geodatabase. Just create a field with the date-type and then go to the properties of your feature-class or dataset and go to "editor tracking" and activate the options you want for your created date-fields.